# unable to connect to service: com.google.android.gms.auth.key.retrieval.service

Tags: firebase, android-studio

i tested my app on API 29, 30, 31 it works good but when i tested on API 19, 20,21, 22, 23 it doesn't works
(In the normal mode the app starts with a splash screen and after goes to the main activity, but in API from 19 to 23 it starts with splash screen, but when it goes to main activity it only shows the background of this activity no button no image no banner ads)

here is the message on Logcat

unable to connect to service: com.google.android.gms.auth.key.retrieval.service.START on com.google.android.gms

Comment: "it doesn't work" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: In the normal mode the app starts with a splash screen and after goes to the main activity, but in API from 19 to 23 it starts with splash screen, but when it goes to main activity it only shows the background of this activity no button no image no banner ads